# How to Reduce Splashscreen time first time load

Tags: angular, splash-screen, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Ia there a way to reduce splash-screen time on {N}+ Angular 2 applications. I tried android-screenshot but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What do u mean by splash screen

Comment: You want to use webpack most likely ;) as most problematic is number of requires in angular modules

Answer (score 1):

The load time depend upon the number of components rendering at the start. With lazy loading you can have a better time start. Mine app load time reduced from 21s to 6s using it. Here is the repo https://github.com/sis0k0/lazyNinjas

Moreover with webpack you can bundle your app which will decrease the overall load time and size of your application.
Checkout the Groceries app in release branch they have implementation with webpack - https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries